# Google is not defined google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);

Tags: cordova, google-maps-api-3

I am trying to add a google map to my cordova app, I copied the code from the developers website to try it out but the error `Uncaught ReferenceError: google is not defined` is appearing. Any idea how to fix this?

EDIT:

```
var map;

function initialize() {
    var mapOptions = {
        zoom: 6
    };
    map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'),
    mapOptions);

    // Try HTML5 geolocation
    if (navigator.geolocation) {
        navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function (position) {
            var pos = new google.maps.LatLng(position.coords.latitude,
            position.coords.longitude);

            var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
                map: map,
                position: pos,
                content: 'Location found using HTML5.'
            });

            map.setCenter(pos);
        }, function () {
            handleNoGeolocation(true);
        });
    } else {
        // Browser doesn't support Geolocation
        handleNoGeolocation(false);
    }
}

function handleNoGeolocation(errorFlag) {
    if (errorFlag) {
        var content = 'Error: The Geolocation service failed.';
    } else {
        var content = 'Error: Your browser doesn\'t support geolocation.';
    }

    var options = {
        map: map,
        position: new google.maps.LatLng(60, 105),
        content: content
    };

    var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow(options);
    map.setCenter(options.position);
}

google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
```

I just copied this code into my html file. The logcat shows google is not defined on the last line. The cordova project I have is a new project so I don't know why this error is showing.

Thanks.

Comment: No idea if you don't provide your code.

Comment: Did you include the script? `<script src="http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false"></script>`

Comment: yes sir I have included it

Comment: Your code works for me. Maybe try a simple `initialize()` or to move the last line in your *document ready* function.

Comment: Funny thing is, I have a working project already, then suddenly it wont work. No Additional plugins were added, just the cordova library.

Answer (score 0):

From the error you have mentioned i understand that the google map api lib is unavailable at the time your code is executed.Make sure you have the added the `google api script code` before including your page 'js' file.

Comment: So Mr. @Shadow what should I do? I am new to Web Development. Thanks.

Comment: @ Miguel Rivera:Could you please  check whether you have included it correctly.Assume you have your script in 'app.js'.So make sure that you have included the `google api script ` before including the 'app.js'. Could you please recheck the same.